# How do I rename sqlite database name and table?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

So I found this link of database infos viewed in a custom listview and it worked and I wanted to modify it. I already changed the methods and class name to books (it was originally countries) and all left is for me to change the db name and tables but when I tried to rename the database name and table but the app did not work. Somebody please help. I'm a just an amateur so I'm having problems thank you in advance. I already did a test run with the original code.

This is the the code:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class BooksDbAdapter {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_CODE = "code";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_CONTINENT = "continent";


 private static final String TAG = "CountriesDbAdapter";
 private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "World";
 private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "Country";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

 private final Context mCtx;

 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
  "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
  KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
  KEY_CODE + "," +
  KEY_NAME + "," +
  KEY_CONTINENT + "," +
  " UNIQUE (" + KEY_CODE +"));";

 private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
   super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }


  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
   db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
     + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
   onCreate(db);
  }
 }

 public BooksDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
  this.mCtx = ctx;
 }

 public BooksDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
  mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
  mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  return this;
 }

 public void close() {
  if (mDbHelper != null) {
   mDbHelper.close();
  }
 }

 public long createBook(String code, String name, 
   String continent) {

  ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
  initialValues.put(KEY_CODE, code);
  initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
  initialValues.put(KEY_CONTINENT, continent);

  return mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
 }

 public boolean deleteAllBooks() {

  int doneDelete = 0;
  doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, null , null);
  Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
  return doneDelete > 0;

 }

 public Cursor fetchBooksByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
  Log.w(TAG, inputText);
  Cursor mCursor = null;
  if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
   mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
     KEY_CODE, KEY_NAME, KEY_CONTINENT}, 
     null, null, null, null, null);

  }
  else {
   mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
     KEY_CODE, KEY_NAME, KEY_CONTINENT}, 
     KEY_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
     null, null, null, null);
  }
  if (mCursor != null) {
   mCursor.moveToFirst();
  }
  return mCursor;

 }

 public Cursor fetchAllBooks() {

  Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
    KEY_CODE, KEY_NAME, KEY_CONTINENT}, 
    null, null, null, null, null);

  if (mCursor != null) {
   mCursor.moveToFirst();
  }
  return mCursor;
 }

 public void insertSomeBook() {
  createBook("AFG","Afghanistan","Asia");
  createBook("ALB","Albania","Europe");
  createBook("DZA","Algeria","Africa");
  createBook("ASM","American", "Samoa");
  createBook("AND","Andorra","Europe");
  createBook("AGO","Angola","Africa");
  createBook("AIA","Anguilla","North America");

 }

}
```

Comment: why do u need to rename?

Comment: Post your error or logcat

Comment: @Darish, I'm actually creating another database for books and I'm just copy pasting those codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I rename sqlite database name and table?

It is possible to have multiple databases in a single app. If you can do without multiple databases, you can have just a single database with multiple tables.

> How to create multiple tables

```
     private static final String TABLE1 =
          "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
          KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
          KEY_CODE + "," +
          KEY_NAME + "," +
          KEY_CONTINENT + "," +
          " UNIQUE (" + KEY_CODE +"));";   

private static final String TABLE2 =
          "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
          KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
          KEY_CODE + "," +
          KEY_NAME + "," +
          KEY_CONTINENT + "," +
          " UNIQUE (" + KEY_CODE +"));";  

            @Override
              public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {    
               db.execSQL(TABLE1);
               db.execSQL(TABLE2);
              }
```